How to run flutter integration tests on github action linux
  - name: Install xvfb
    run: sudo apt-get install xvfb

  - name: Start Xvfb
    run: |
      sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
      echo "Xvfb started"

  - name: Run integration tests
    run: |
      export DISPLAY=:99
      cd pangea_flutter
      echo "Running integration tests"
      flutter test -d linux ${{inputs.test_file}}
    timeout-minutes: 20

GHA worklow never completes. It just keeps processing without any error. When I check logs I see test 0: awaiting connection to test device.
Then I manually cancel the job.

There are many approaches for this answer. but once that ive tried is using libglu1-mesa for graphical applications. i used subosito/flutter-action to handle the Flutter setup which makes the approach much more faster and efficient rather than doing it manually from scratch and also Xvfb setup to properly start the virtual display needed for running integration tests so thats its better in the test scenarios if you was to e2e run it.
This is the code which as made by me for your reference.
name: Flutter Integration Tests

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      DISPLAY: :99

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libglu1-mesa xvfb

    - name: Set up Flutter
      uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      with:
        flutter-version: 'stable'

    - name: Install Flutter dependencies
      run: flutter pub get

    - name: Start Xvfb
      run: |
        sudo Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1280x1024x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        echo "Xvfb started"

    - name: Run integration tests
      run: |
        cd your_directory_name_flutter
        flutter test --machine integration_test 2>&1 | tee integration_test.log
    timeout-minutes: 20


On running this In GHA i get Web devices are not supported for integration tests yet. . No test runs.

I get Job is waiting for a hosted runner to come online in logs on GHA when I use flutter test -d linux integration_test/fil1.dart 2>&1 | tee integration_test.log
